# 複数のPHPファイルで乱数を共有したい

Tags: php

同じ乱数の数字を2つのPHPファイルで使えるようにしたいのですが、違う数字が表示されてしまいます。

[ransuu.php]

```
<?php
 $random = ran(2,9);
?>
```

[file1.php]

```
<?php
include 'ransuu.php';
echo $random; //　例）２
?>
```

[file2.php]

```
<?php
include 'ransuu.php';
echo $random; //　例）４
?>
```

echoした時の結果がどちらも同じ数字になってほしいのですが、方法がわからないので、どなたか教えていただけますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 乱数なので違う表示がされてしまうのは正しい動作ですね。作成した乱数データをどこかに保存する必要がありますが、データベースやファイルシステムの利用は可能ですか？

Comment: 関数名が `ran` ではなく正しくは `rand` かと思います。 / @keitaro_so さんの補足として、乱数生成は **関数を呼び出すたび** に新しい値になります。

Comment: @keitaro_so 回答ありがとうございます。MySQLを利用しています。やはり保存しなければいけないんですね。

Comment: @cubick 回答ありがとうございます。私の打ち間違いで「d」が抜けておりました。修正しておきます。呼び出すたびに毎回乱数の生成が実行されるんですね。

Answer (score 0):

file1.php,file2.phpにアクセスするたびに新しい乱数が発生してしまっているので
複数のPHPファイルで同じ値を使用するには基本的にはセッション変数を使います。

ransuu.phpで

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['random']) $_SESSION['random'] = rand(2,9); ?>
```

としたあと、
file1.php,file2.phpで

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['random'])) echo $_SESSION['random']; ?>
```

とします。

Comment: WEBに限る場合はこの方法でよいですが、セッション自体が存在しないケースもありますので、セッション変数を上記の用途に用いるのは、正しいとはいえないと思います。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは

質問者様がご自身でコメントされているとおり、どこかに数値を保存して取り出す必要があると思います。
候補としては下記が考えられます。

- Singletonにしたオブジェクト(一時的な用途に限る/コンストラクタで乱数を設定する)
- Memcacheなどのサービス
- ファイル
- セッション(WEBを利用しているなら適切かもしれません)
- データベース